# sql rows to columns. sql 2008R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
create table temptest 
(lid varchar(10), dat varchar(20))

insert into temptest (lid,dat) values ('11','first')
insert into temptest (lid,dat) values ('11','second')
insert into temptest (lid,dat) values ('11','third')

insert into temptest (lid,dat) values ('12','box')
insert into temptest (lid,dat) values ('12','circle')
insert into temptest (lid,dat) values ('12','trap')

insert into temptest (lid,dat) values ('14','star')
insert into temptest (lid,dat) values ('14','planet')
```

I want the results to be:

```
lid, dat1, dat2, dat3
11,first,second,third
12, box, circle, trap
14, star, planet, <blank>
```

Comment: What have you tried? You might try searching this site. This has been asked and answered hundreds of times. You either want PIVOT, cross tab or conditional aggregation. Those are all valid options for this.

Comment: What have you tried so far???  Have you even done some research???  There are tons of example on the web.  It's part of programmer's job to do research on stuffs you don't know.

Comment: Also if your requirement is that they are listed in the comma-separated string in the same order that they are inserted, you need something in the original table to indicate order (e.g. identity / datetime).

Comment: Well I don't appreciate getting dinged for asking a question. I have researched pivot, didn't offer me a great option. I researched rows to columns to no great avail. I don't care about order, I just want the resulting data as stated in the question. If you want to point me to something on SO, then please do and I won't bother anyone about this. But if you can't answer the question, please show some restraint.

Comment: @fox-jazz Wasn't me, but you didn't get dinged for asking a question. You got dinged for asking a question that has been asked hundreds of times before. A little searching would get you an answer faster than typing your question, and without people having to put in the effort of answering it *one more redundant time*.

Comment: Wasn't my ding either but pretty sure it is because this has been asked so many times.

Comment: It looks like someone answered easily on sqlservercentral.com  Much nicer place to be. bye.

Comment: Sure, some places are easier to get spoon-fed, but that doesn't necessarily make them a better place for you (or any of us) to be, in the long run. You might want to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9953/could-we-please-be-a-bit-nicer-to-new-users) (yes, in full). There's a reason this is the most popular Q & A site, don't let your mismatched expectations chase you away. And please remember a down-vote is just taking away measly reputation points, which are meaningless.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no question.

Comment: How can NO question be answered?  There is certainly a question, but not literally, only implied. I think you need post as a sql server how to turn rows into columns as the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was answered on SQL-server central also with this:

```
` ;
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY lid ORDER BY dat) AS rn
    FROM #temptest
)

SELECT lid,
MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN dat END) AS dat1,
MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN dat END) AS dat2,
MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN dat END) AS dat3
FROM CTE
GROUP BY lid`
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
;with sourceTable as
(
  Select lid, 
         dat, 
         case RN 
                 when 1 then 'dat1' 
                 when 2 then 'dat2' 
                 when 3 then 'dat3' 
         end as dat#
  from(
    select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by lid order by lid ) as RN from temptest
    )as K
) 
Select lid,[dat1],[dat2],[dat3] from sourceTable
pivot
(
   MIN(dat) for dat# in ([dat1],[dat2],[dat3])
)as P
```